# Batch conversion of Modis Swath (level 2) data

Tags: gdal, modis

I'm using very MODIS Swath products and need to import some bands to TIF. I'm working with MOD06_L2, MOD07_L2 and MOD11_L2 products and the MRT Swath isn't work as well. I'm using the following code:

```
gdalwarp -of GTIFF -tps -t_srs EPSG:4674 HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD11_L2.A2014001.1305.006.2016179220648.hdf":MOD_Swath_LST:LST LST.tif
```

Unfortunately, the output image is blank. I need to convert 3 years of data for the products listed above.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the image is blank? I used the same input image and the same code using GDAL 2.1.3 and OS X 10.12.6:

[image]

The resulting output opened in QGIS:

[image]

Check you GDAL version or compute histogram of the output .tif to be sure if the image has only blank or NULL pixels.

Comment: My GDAL version is 2.1.0 e and the error can be observed in line:
Creating output file that is 5793P x 12L.

I'm trying to install another version of GDAL to test again.

Comment: Problem solved when I has intalled GDAL 2.2.1. If you have the same problem just upgrade your GDAL for this version. See ya.

Comment: @ArgemiroLucenaAraujo great! You're welcome